# facebook Sharer popup window

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, metadata

The FB sharer popup window displays the data of the page, not the metadata I have inserted in the php link.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p%5Btitle%5D=Google&p%5Burl%5D=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&p%5Bsummary%5D=Google search engine&p%5Bimages%5D%5B0%5D=https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png
"onClick="return fbs_click(626, 305)" target="_blank" title="Share">FACEBOOK</a>
```

It seems the to be caused by the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fbs_click(width, height) {
var leftPosition, topPosition;
leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
var windowFeatures = "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=no,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no";
u=location.href;
t=document.title;
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer', windowFeatures);
return false;
}
</script>
```

How can I display the correct data in the popup window?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to add custom metadata, use following code:

```
<a id="fb-share" style='text-decoration:none;' type="icon_link" onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_DESCRIPTION&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=580,height=325');" href="javascript: void(0)">Share</a>
```

**UPDATE:**

I wrote a little JS code for Facebook Share.

- JS Code: https://gist.github.com/Stichoza/4942775
- Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/

**Javascript:**

```
function fbShare(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
        var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
        var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
        window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + title + '&p[summary]=' + descr + '&p[url]=' + url + '&p[images][0]=' + image, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width='+winWidth+',height='+winHeight);
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:fbShare('http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/', 'Fb Share', 'Facebook share popup', 'http://goo.gl/dS52U', 520, 350)">Share</a>
```

Comment: perfect, thank you :) now if I only could have the popup in the middle of the page instead of left upper corner..

Comment: @ThomasBLund check out my edited answer, everything works fine :)

Comment: this is a continue (and solution) to my other question about "og-meta tags for several share buttons" - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818698/open-graph-meta-tags-for-several-share-buttons - thank you Stichoza

Comment: Note that detailed arguments (title, summary, images) have been deprecated and removed, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22969530/368691.

Answer (score 0):

the sharing link not working any more after resarch I found this you should update your function on this new share url

```
href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=&t=" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL)); return false;"> </a>
```