# Facebook iframe with callback

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am using

```
<div class="fb-share-button"  data-href="" data-layout="button_count" oncklick=""></div>
```

to have Facebook sharing on my page.

Now I am wondering why it is not possible to add any events to fire a function if the share button was clicked like this:

```
$(".fb-share-button").click(function(event){ 
//do stuff 
});
```

Is there any way i can achieve to add a function to the click?
I want to be able to use a ajax callback to store into my database that the button was clicked, but i can not use an app id as it is a site for different customers.

Anyone with a solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook like and share button with callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116001/facebook-like-and-share-button-with-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom javascript won't be able to manipulate the contents of your iframe in the way that you want. Unfortunately that's the way modern browsers implement iframes.

**Most common solution**

Your best bet is to make a custom facebook share button that you have more control over, using facebook sharer links.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=blah.com">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Source: http://www.sharelinkgenerator.com/

**Alternate method:**

You can also link/redirect to a facebook dialog, though by the looks you need to create a facebook app, which is a pain.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?
  app_id=145634995501895
  &display=popup
  &href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F
  &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer
```

Reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: Not if you use the JS SDK. Btw that's the only option you have in this case because the share is trigger by a user click, not a server-side app.

Comment: Thanks.
Did some further research and in combination with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829040/facebook-sharer-popup-window/14829742#14829742
it works pretty neat.